# Any way to preserve spaces in names when calling transform()?

Tags: r

Is there any way to preserve spaces in a data.frame's column names when calling transform()?  Currently they get munged:

```
> transform(data.frame('a b'=1, check.names=F), `c d`=`a b`)
  a.b c.d
1   1   1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just feed `check.names=F` into `transform`:

```
> transform(data.frame('a b'=1, check.names=F), `c d`=`a b`,check.names=F)
  a b c d
1   1   1
```

However, I don't see this mentioned in the documentation for `?transform`!

Comment: Damn, shoulda just tried it instead of RTFM! (I had also seen it was missing.)

Comment: check.names=F in data.frame is not neccessary as it is default.